# How to count how many times a name appear?

Tags: sql

I have a table like the following:

```
ID     X     Y
5      2     0
5      1     1
5      3     3
4      -2    1
4      0     0
3      5     -3
```

I would like to count how the records for each `ID`

```
ID count
5    3
4    2
3    1
```

Comment: That's a basic `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS count FROM data GROUP BY ID`

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much all

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS count FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID
```